# Making Terrain Strip in c++ & returning 2d array

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm screwing around with opengl in c++, this is my first time really writing anything in c++, so I'm having troubles with pointers and arrays. I'd like to make a function that makes a strip of terrain (represented by an array of vertices, each vertex being an array of 3 floats) and returns it. This 2d array (unknown sized array of 3 sized arrays) can then be rendered with gl triangles. I'm not having any trouble with rendering it, but when my code runs currently, when I log the values of the vertices in the array local to the function, everything is fine, but in the main source, the values aren't logged correctly.

tl;dr:
How can I generate an array of arrays in a c++ function.

Here's my function right now:

```
float** makeTerrainStrip(float tile, unsigned int tiles)
{
    float** strip = new float*[(tiles + 1) * 2];
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < tiles; i++) {
        float x = i * tile;
        float y = 0;
        float z1 = 0;
        float z2 = tile;
        float v1[3] = {x, y, z1};
        float v2[3] = {x, y, z2};
        strip[i * 2] = v1;
        strip[i * 2 + 1] = v2;
    }
    std::cout << strip[0][0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << strip[0][1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << strip[0][2] << std::endl;
    return strip;
}
```

and it gets called from the main source here:

```
strip = makeTerrainStrip(1, 5); // strip is a global defined earlier
std::cout << strip[0][0] << std::endl;
std::cout << strip[0][1] << std::endl;
std::cout << strip[0][2] << std::endl;
```

Here's the output:

```
// in the function
4
0
0
// in the main source
4
1.26749e+029
7987.1
```

Comment: You stuff your array full of pointers to local variables. Those variables are created and destroyed anew on each iteration of the loop, and in any case definitely don't exist anymore when the function returns. So outside that loop, it's an array full of dangling pointers pointing to random garbage.

Comment: Okay, so when a variable in a pointer is trashed, it's instance in the pointer is trashed, thanks. How can I fix this to return the correct array?

Comment: You need to design a self-contained data structure - not an array of pointers without clear idea where they point to. My guess would be, you probably want something like this: `struct Vertex { float x, y, z;}; std::vector<Vertex> strip;`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: I don't know why I care, but why do you always answer questions in comments? There's clearly a note in the comment box before you begin typing advising against that.

Comment: Thanks Igor, if you wanna put that in an answer, I'll mark it correct

Comment: @BenjaminLindley It is rare that a question is stated clearly and unambiguously, and that I feel I understand it well enough to give conclusive and exhaustive answer (I'm also often too lazy to invest sufficient effort in doing so). So I make a comment instead, which often leads to further discussion and clarification. I guess one way to put it would be, I'm not sure how high the quality bar for an answer is, and I tend to err on the side of modesty.